# Combining Google and Factual APIs?

Tags: google-maps, factual, google-maps-autocomplete

I am using the Factual API along with the Google Maps API to get data for Restaurants in a certain city. As the name suggests, Factual deals with Factual data and does not include Restaurant images as apart of their API.

Does anybody know if it is possible for me to compare the Place ID in factual to the Place ID in maps and get the correct Restaurant image associated with it?

Answer (score 0):

The ids are distinct. To get pictures do a Google Places text search on the factual name. Use the results[0].place_id to do a Place details search.  I do this and get results about 95% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Google Places API premium package rather than Factual?  I'm look at which one to pick, but if I'm going to be using maps, why pay twice?  Maybe I'm missing something.
The big difference is downloading the data for factual vs google api, but it doesn't matter for me, using an API is probably easier than importing data anyway.